# How can I fix this error with django-autocomplete-light - Importerror No Module Named Shortcuts?

Tags: django, django-autocomplete-light

So, for two days now I have been struggling to set up django-autocomplete-light to do the most basic autocompletes, but to no avail. I've ran into so many problems and so many errors that I cannot specify them here to solicit a clear solution.

So, what I am attempting to do now is create a basic django application, from scratch and drop in the "basic" example from the django-autocomplete-light repository. Doing this to try to create a reproducible problem so I can get support.

However, this too has been frustrating. I have ran into this error now...

```
  File "/Users/josh/.virtualenvs/testaclite/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 21, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Users/josh/.virtualenvs/testaclite/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 115, in populate
    app_config.ready()
  File "/Users/josh/.virtualenvs/testaclite/lib/python2.7/site-packages/autocomplete_light/apps.py", line 10, in ready
    autocomplete_light.autodiscover()
  File "/Users/josh/.virtualenvs/testaclite/lib/python2.7/site-packages/autocomplete_light/registry.py", line 290, in autodiscover
    autodiscover_modules('autocomplete_light_registry')
  File "/Users/josh/.virtualenvs/testaclite/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 74, in autodiscover_modules
    import_module('%s.%s' % (app_config.name, module_to_search))
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Users/josh/Development/python/testaclite/aclite/basic/autocomplete_light_registry.py", line 1, in <module>
    import autocomplete_light.shortcuts as autocomplete_light
ImportError: No module named shortcuts
```

What can I do to resolve this?

Comment: you have to checkout master for that. .Looks like the shortcuts file came into existence 8 days ago (in the rc3)

Comment: @karthikr Thanks. That appears to have solved this issue.

Answer (score 5):

Really, credit for this answer should go to karthikr for pointing out to me the problem. To fix it, I installed django-autocomplete-light from a particular branch that had recently been updated. I used the following command to do so:

```
pip install -e git+git://github.com/yourlabs/django-autocomplete-light.git@2.1.0rc3#egg=autocomplete_light
```